# Google Cloud SQL going into read only mode

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Every couple of days or so, when I look in our app engine logs, I see this error when the app is trying to connect to a Google SQL instance

```
Query failed w/ error: The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
```

I've read that this can happen during a maintenance window, but that is configured to be once a week. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Is this for a v2 instance? I suspect it's something about HA (failover replica). Please email your full instance name with a reference to this post to cloud-sql@google.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to Cloud SQL instance being backed up while you're performing your query.

CloudSQL instances are backed up daily by default, and **while backup jobs run the tables are put in read-only mode**.

Please see this official page for further info:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/backup-recovery/backups#how_backups_affect_instance_operations

Hope this helps.